# Why does button component in WP editor keep rendering anchor tag in front-end?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am in the process of developing a block based form plugin for WP. The main form block will support nested blocks - the button core component being one of them.

Problem is that whenever I include the button component, the thing that gets rendered in the front-end is an anchor tag instead. I checked - the ***link & anchor options are empty*** in the button sidebar options (in editor).

So shouldn't a button have been rendered instead? What am I missing here?

The official Wordpress reference guide states the following -

> The presence of a href prop determines whether an anchor element is rendered instead of a button.
>
> Props not included in this set will be applied to the a or button element
>
> Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/button/#props)

Also, is there any way to disable the anchor options when I am inserting a button component inside my form?

Wordpress version: 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `core/button` block only renders an `<a>` tag. [You can see for yourself in the source code](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/button/save.js#L64). The `core/button` block was not intended to create an actual `<button>` element (for submitting a form like in your example).

What you'll need to do is create your own custom block that *does* output a `<button>` HTML element.

Comment: Then how does one explain the following?

```The presence of a href prop determines whether an anchor element is rendered instead of a button.

Props not included in this set will be applied to the a or button element.```

Reference - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/button/#props

Comment: The "the link & anchor options are empty in the button sidebar options (in editor)" line is confusing to me, since if you're using the [`Button`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/components/src/button) _component_ (which is part of `@wordpress/components`), there shouldn't be _any_ settings in the editor in which to check. Only the `core/button` _block_ would show you options in the sidebar. I have tested and can confirm `<Button onClick={ () => handleOnClick() }>Button Text</Button>` _does_ render a `<button>` element. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: To clarify, I think you may be confusing the [`core/button` block](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/button), and the [`Button` component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/components/src/button). The `core/button` can be added as a nested _block_ in the editor. The `Button` component cannot. The `Button` component can only be used in JS code.

Comment: Ah I think I see my mistake.. Yes, I added the `core/button` block via drag and drop, and that got rendered as an `<a>` tag.  The link that I referred to belongs to Button component - like you pointed out - which can render both `<a>` and `<button`>.

Comment: So is there no way to render a button element in the front-end while using the Gutenberg block editor (without the help of custom blocks)?

Comment: I don't have any problem creating a custom block - it's just that I want to be absolutely sure.

Comment: As of the writing of this comment, currently there is no way to render a `<button>` using the built in `Blocks`. You'll need to create a custom block.

Comment: Okay. I'll do that. Thanks for the info. :)